# How do I "save" groups from DataFrame.groupby to separate variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a DataFrame with WhatsApp messages that I `.groupby`ed by the sender. Can I somehow split and save the entire DataFrame or only a Series into separate variables?

So say I have senders A, B, C. Can I get 3 new dataframes with respectively only senders A, B, C or a series with only a column where the sender once was A, B or C?

Comment: can you show the code for how you are constructing your dataframe from the data ?

Comment: `dfa, dfb, dfc = [_, s for s in df.groupby('sender')]`

Comment: @mounaim what do you mean?

Comment: @rafaelc I'm not familiar with what you did within the list comprehension. What does the underscore before the `s for s...` mean?

Comment: `df.groupby` is an iterable. The structure of this iterable is `(index, data_frame)`. That means if you do `for i in df.groupby(...): print I`, you see a tuple with two positions. The first is the index, the second is the sub-data-frame groupbed by that index. `index` here will be whatever thing you have grouped on. So, if you have a `df` with three senders (say, Mike, John and Paul), `list(df.groupby('sender'))` will return something like `[(Mike, df_mike), (John, df_john), (Paul, df_paul)]`. When you do `for (_, s) in df.groupby`, you automatically assign `Mike` to the variable `_` and

Comment: `df_make to the variable `s`). It is a convention in python to use `_` (underscore) whenever a variable is not used, which is why I did that.

Comment: @rafaelc write an answer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, you **cannot** dynamically create new variables within an iteration without explicitly defining them. Eg by:

```
for sender in senders:
    df_{sender} = df[df["sender"] == sender]
```

Because of this, if you want to split the `DataFrame` into multiple variables, you will have to "hardcode" your solution, where all variables are defined. Eg. by `df_A = df[df["sender"] == "A"]` etc. I would recommend you to use `df.groupby("sender")` followed by the appropriate calculations/transformation, since the object you will be performing on only contains one sender at a time.

If you instead want to save multiple `DataFrame`'s as CSV-files, one for each sender, you could try:

```
df.groupby("sender").apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(f"sub_df_{x.name}.csv"))
```

x.name is the index which `df` is group on, so the corresponding sender in this case.

Comment: Follow up question:
I want to do this so I can get separate histograms for the distribution of messages over time of the day. Are you by chance familiar with seaborn and know if I can achieve this even without separating the df before?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing `to_csv` inside the apply function

Comment: @Marcus, *“...you cannot dynamically create new variables within an iteration”* — the standard way is to use a list or dictionary instead, e. g. instead names `df_A`, `df_B`, `df_C` use `df_['A']`, `df_['B']`, `df_['C']`, where `df_` is a dictionary.

Comment: @1tr3mm3l7 I know you can achieve it without separating the df, although I'm not familiar enough with seaborn to give you exact instructions. You could maybe find some inspiration here? https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/07/15/pandas-groupby-multiple-columns-plot.html

Comment: @rafaelc Could you expand? If the use case involves saving a lot CSV-files based on unique values in a column, why would you not use `.groupby(col).apply(save_df)`?